# Call a method from a form (html)

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I have a form where I introduce different parameters and I want to save them in a database (SQL). For that I am using a method but I don't know how to call it from the form, how do I specify that action?

```
<form class="input-data" action="NewBookMethod" runat="server">
<div id="title">
<input type="text" id="inputTitle">
</div>
<div id="summary">
<input type="summary" id="inputSummary">
</div>
<button id="btn" type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

I am using a Web Form in Visual Studio, the form is in the .aspx file and the method is in the .aspx.cs file.

Thanks.

Comment: Action should be a webpage, like *Page.aspx*

Comment: you have to post back to a URL, not a method. In WebForms this usually ends up being an aspx page.

Comment: start with a tutorial, its very easy, just build an aspx page

Comment: @RicardoPontual thanks. Can I call a specific method from that page or just load all of it?

Comment: Yes you can, but not using `form` submit, that will submit to `Page_Load` method. You can pass some value that "tell" `Page_Load` what you want to do, or use a `asp:buttom` with `runat='server'` attribute to run an specific method, or use an `Ajax`call, some options you can use.